# ForLoop calls function only one time

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I have a fourLoop that calls my function addMarker, but I only get the results of one loop.  The console log that I have nested in the loop returns the proper array length.  I am curious about this issue as I suspect that I lack attention to some concept. This is for the Google maps, places, and geocode API's(I removed my key for security, so if you just read through the initMap function all the relevant issues reside in that scope).

UPDATE: I logged the "loopData" and I am get the correct number of iteration, BUT it is only the data from the last index.That points me towards the error being in the the forLoop where I parse the the initial response from the Google places API. The code there is this chunk:
(The purpose of the following code block is to iterate over an array of objects, and to grab certain values on each iteration, and to push those values to a new array "placesDataLocations" of collected objects. Right now I am getting the correct amount of objects, but each object has the exact same value as the LAST qualifying object of my API response data.)

```
const gym = {}
const placesDataLocations = []

for (let i = 0; i < placesData.results.length; i++) {
  if (placesData.results[i].business_status === 'OPERATIONAL') {
    // Array of Objects in form {gym: {id: 10, quantity: 10} }
    gym.location = placesData.results[i].geometry.location
    gym.name = placesData.results[i].name
    gym.address = placesData.results[i].vicinity
    placesDataLocations.push({ gym: gym })
  }
}
console.log(placesDataLocations)
initMap(googleGeocodeLat, googleGeocodeLng, placesDataLocations)
```

})

The initial API response data looks like this:
[image]

UPDATE2: So I am abandoning the first method to create a new array of objects and trying out the .map method like this:

```
const placesDataLocations = []
  for (let i = 0; i < placesData.results.length; i++) {
    if (placesData.results[i].business_status === 'OPERATIONAL') {
      placesDataLocations.push({ 
        placesData.results[i].map(data => {
        return {
          location: data.geometry.location,
          name: data.name,
          address: data.vicinity
        }
  })
 }) 
}
```

}
Right now the console is telling me that "placesData.results[i].map" is not a function. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
const mapModal = document.querySelector('#googleMap')
const originalMapContent = mapModal.innerHTML

// displaying the map
function initMap (locationLatitude, locationLongitude, gymCoordinates) {
  // Map options
  const options = {
    center: { lat: locationLatitude, lng: locationLongitude },
    zoom: 10
  }

  // New map
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), options)

  // Add markers
  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: locationLatitude, lng: locationLongitude },
    map: map
  // icon: '...'
  })

  // const coordinates = gymCoordinates
  for (let i = 0; i < gymCoordinates.length; i++) {
    console.log(gymCoordinates.length);
    addMarker(gymCoordinates[i])
  }

  // Add marker function - displays multiple different markers
  function addMarker (loopData) {
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: loopData.gym.location,
      map: map,
      icon: 'https://img.icons8.com/offices/2x/map-pin.png'
    })
    
    // Add infoWindow
    const infoWindowContent = `<h6>${loopData.gym.name}</h6><div>${loopData.gym.address}</div>`
    const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({

      content: infoWindowContent
    })

    // Function required to display the info window on map
    marker.addListener('click', () => {
      infoWindow.open(map, marker)
    })
  }
}

const apiKey = '&key=key-removed'

const searchButton = document.getElementById('gymFind')

searchButton.addEventListener('click', async function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  // getting the zip code input
  const zipCode = document.querySelector('#userZip').value.trim()
  const googleGeocodeAPI = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${zipCode},US${apiKey}`

  // call to API to grab latitude and longitude from the zip code user input
  const res = await fetch(googleGeocodeAPI)
    .catch(error => console.error({ error }))

  const data1 = await res.json()

  const googleGeocodeLat = data1.results[0].geometry.location.lat
  const googleGeocodeLng = data1.results[0].geometry.location.lng

  // console.log(lat, lng)

  // Google Places API requires Proxy server header to enable cross-origin-resource-sharing (CORS)
  var corsProxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'

  const googlePlacesAPI = `${corsProxy}https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${googleGeocodeLat},${googleGeocodeLng}&radius=4500&type=gym&keyword=exercise${apiKey}`

  // call to API where list of gyms is generated using latitude and longitude of zip code
  const res2 = await fetch(googlePlacesAPI)
    .catch(error => console.error({ error }))

  const placesData = await res2.json()

  console.log(placesData)
  const gym = {}
  const placesDataLocations = []

  for (let i = 0; i < placesData.results.length; i++) {
    if (placesData.results[i].business_status === 'OPERATIONAL') {
      // Array of Objects in form {gym: {id: 10, quantity: 10} }
      gym.location = placesData.results[i].geometry.location
      gym.name = placesData.results[i].name
      gym.address = placesData.results[i].vicinity
      placesDataLocations.push({ gym: gym })
    }
  }
  console.log(placesDataLocations)
  initMap(googleGeocodeLat, googleGeocodeLng, placesDataLocations)
})

const modalCloseButton = document.querySelector('#modal-close-button')

// clearing the contents of the map modal on close to prepare for the next query
modalCloseButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  mapModal.innerHTML = originalMapContent
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link
      type="text/css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="assets/css/materialize.min.css"
      media="screen,projection"
    />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <script
      defer
      src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js"
      integrity="sha384-g5uSoOSBd7KkhAMlnQILrecXvzst9TdC09/VM+pjDTCM+1il8RHz5fKANTFFb+gQ"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <style>
      .section .card-image #foodImg {
        height: 200 pX;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Nutrition & Health</title>
  </head>

  <body id="home" class="scrollspy">

          <!-- SECTION Google Map and ZIP CODE-->
          <div id="gymFinder"  class="col s12 m4">
              <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-content">
                      <h3> <span class="card-title"><u>Let's Get Healthy</u></span></h3>
                      <p style="font-size:20px">Please enter your zip code for a map of work-out places in your area. </p>
                      <div class="input-field">
                          <input onkeyup="numbersOnly(this)" type="text" id="userZip"/>
                          <label for="userZip">Zip Code</label>
                        </div>

                  </div>
                  <div id="gymFind" class="card-action">
                    <a href="#mapmodal" class="btn waves-effect waves-light modal-trigger" id="map-button">Find A Gym</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>        
      </div>


          <div id="mapmodal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <a id="modal-close-button" href="#" class="teal modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn">Close</a>
              </div>
          </div>

           <!-- SECTION: Footer-->

    <section class="section teal darken-2 white-text  ">
      <div class="container">
        Food Searcher&copy; 2019
      <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="#!">Created by King Major</a>  
    </div> 
    </section>

    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 
    <!-- External Scrips -->
    <script src="./assets/js/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/restricted_login.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/search.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Maps Scripts -->
    <script src="./assets/js/googlemap-test.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY-REMOVED&callback=initMap"></script>


    <!-- Internal Scripts -->
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // Custom JS & jQuery here
        // INIT SIDENAVE
        $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
        // INIT SLIDER
        $('.slider').slider({
          indicators: false,
          height: 300,
          transition: 700,
          interval: 6000
        });
        
        
        //INIT SCROLLSPY
        $('.scrollspy').scrollSpy();
        // INIT SELECT MENU
        $('select').material_select();
        //INIT MODALS
        $('.modal').modal();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in `addMarker` and inspected what `loopData` looks like each time the function is called?

Comment: @StephenP Thanks. I just updated the question with the results of a console log I nested in addMarker. I believe there may be an issue with the way that I generate the gym object.

Comment: it looks like you are overwriting the gym object with the location, name and address on every loop thus only seeing the values from last pass through. try creating a new object in the loop

Comment: You need a new object on each iteration, move `const gym = {}` inside the loop

Comment: Why map? You would map over the results.... not inside.... just move the const like I said....

Comment: @epascarello I followed your original response, but my update and your answer were simultaneous. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the same object on every iteration and pushing that same object onto your array. You need a brand new object.

```
const placesDataLocations = []

for (let i = 0; i < placesData.results.length; i++) {
  if (placesData.results[i].business_status === 'OPERATIONAL') {
    // Array of Objects in form {gym: {id: 10, quantity: 10} }
    const gym = {
      location: placesData.results[i].geometry.location,
      name: placesData.results[i].name,
      address: placesData.results[i].vicinity
    }
    placesDataLocations.push({ gym: gym })
  }
}
```

If you want to use map, you would also have to loop with filter.

```
const placesDataLocations = placesData.results
  .filter(function (result) {
    return result.business_status === 'OPERATIONAL';
  }).map( function(result) {
    return { 
      gym: {
        location: result.geometry.location,
        name: result.name,
        address: result.vicinity
      }
    }
  });
```